# android ImageView/ RelativeLayout increase size by Dragging the corner of ImageView/ RelativeLayout

Tags: android

i want to increase the size of  ImageView/ RelativeLayout by Dragging the corner of  ImageView/ RelativeLayout. But no difference in width and set it bottom. I set it by using android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and also set image in imageview. but how to drag i don't know. Is there is any option available in Android? can any one suggest some solution for this? pls help me

Answer (score 2):

you can use **onTouch()** for the ImageView.

Once it is touched show a small image at the edge of the imageview. And on touching that image and moving(onTouch() gives the pixel positions until you touch it) you will be getting the pixel positions. Based on that you can set the height and width of the imageview.

Comment: yes , i used. but it's not perfectaly work. @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getX() >= img.getWidth() - 20 && event.getX() <= img.getWidth() || event.getY() >= img.getHeight() - 20
&& event.getY() <= img.getHeight()) {
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
params.width = (int) event.getX();    params.height = (int) event.getY();
   img.setLayoutParams(params);
   
  }
  return true;
 }

Comment: I dont think your logic is right !! and why are you using Align_parent_bottom ??? if you just want to drag the corner of the imageview to make its size bigger just set the height and width of the imageview when onTouch() is called based on some logic